# JQUERY tabs PHP Google charts

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have 3 pages(p1.php,p2.php, p3.php), each of them working fine -contains php code and javascript and as end result are some google charts.
I would like to combine these pages in  Tabs

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="p1.php">Chart1</a></li>
  <li><a href="p2.php">Chart1</a></li>
  <li><a href="p3.php">Chart1</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="ajax-content">Google Charts</div>
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#nav li a").click(function() {

    $("#ajax-content").empty().append("<div id='loading'><img src='images/loading.gif' 
  alt='Loading' /></div>");
    $("#nav li a").removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');

    $.ajax({ url: this.href, success: function(html) {
        $("#ajax-content").empty().append(html);
        }
});
return false;
});
});
```

The issue is , that it shows empty page, instead of graph. 
done some testing by printing text on each pages.It works fine
Graphs are not drawing

Comment: The ajax, does it return anything if you log it? check in devl tool network or firebug, do u get a response?  have tried $("#ajax-content").html(html) instead?

Comment: $("#ajax-content").html(html) - Instead of ?

Comment: instead of appending it $("#ajax-content").append(), just to see if you are actually getting a result

Comment: there were no changes.Funny thing is that as seperate pages it works, but when put on tabs, its blank

Comment: So do you get any result thru the ajax call? Is there any error shown in your console?

Comment: I wthink I will create alternative version http://jsfiddle.net/kentcoast/PJbAR/2/